# Cannot get "set show-mode-in-prompt on" on OSX

Tags: bash, macos, vi, readline

I'm using bash v4.4 with "set editing-mode vi". I cannot get the vi-mode to show in the prompt.

I added "set show-mode-in-prompt on" to my ~/.inputrc file, but for some reason it does not work.

My Readline version is 7.0.

When I type "man readline", I see there a line that reads:

"show-mode-in-prompt (Off)"

Which means it's probably off.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You should be adding persistent options to ~/.vimrc and not ~/.inputrc.

Comment: @RamanSailopal It has nothing to do with vim.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the `man readline` output you're seeing is just explaining the default value for the setting, not necessarily telling you that you've still got it set to 'off'.

Maybe your default shell is still the old, system default one? Try checking with: `echo $BASH_VERSION` (It won't necessarily be the same as when running `bash --version`)

If it turns out it's the old version then [updating your system's default shell to a newer version of bash](http://clubmate.fi/upgrade-to-bash-4-in-mac-os-x/) might fix things!

Comment: Thanks. Turns out your suspicion was correct: my bash version was indeed 3.x. I updated it to 4 and now it's working as expected.